Tabulator .setColumns() works only once
I'm using Tabulator JS 6.2.0 using the .setData() method to load JSON into the table.
The promise returned by setData() then calls .setColumns() to push column-headings etc. in. This works fine once. Unfortunately, calling .setColumns() again with different column-setup does not do anything. Using automatic column generation, it works but my JSON-Data has a different column-sequence (order) that I need in the GUI, so this is not suitable for me.
Can anybody give me a hint how to change the column-layout using .setColumns()?
Thanks!
Sascha

You will need to provide a link to a JS Fiddle or similar that demos your issue, it is very hard to offer advice without seeing your table setup

After removing the language definition, it seems to work. Thanks anyway for your quick reply.
